# iOS Change frame of UITabBarButton in UITabBar

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

In my app I have a `UITabBarController` in which I give custom selected/unselected images in my `AppDelegate` as follows:

```
UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home-tab-selected"];
UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home-tab"];
UITabBar *tabBar = tabController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage];
```

The images I have are 100x100, much larger than the normal tab bar items. All works well, and my images are placed nicely and look great.

The issue I am having is that the frame of the underlaying `UITabBarButton` remains 76x48, leaving only a small portion of my tabs 'touchable'. (Image below with a border around the frame)

[image: frame smaller than tab image]

To attempt to fix this, in my subcalssed `UITabBarController` `viewDidLoad`, I go through each `UITabBarButton`, and set the frame as follows:

```
for (UIView* subView in self.tabBar.subviews)
{
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITabBarButton")])
    {

        [subView setFrame:CGRectMake(subView.frame.origin.x, subView.frame.origin.y, 100, 100)];


    }
}
```

After I do that, I log the frames and they do change-- BUT the frame never changes in my tab bar-- I still only see and can touch in the smaller red box.

Is this because Apple does not allow you to change these frames or am I doing something wrong here?

Any help apperciated! Thanks!

EDIT:

In the end I just ended up making my tab images smaller. I found a height of 70px still picks up most touches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The layout of your `UITabBarController`'s view might change after loading: Additional `UITabBarItem`s could be added, of the user could switch to landscape orientation.

Before iOS 6, there wasn't a way to configure complex layouts. Since `UITabBar` is a very old class, it's most likely doing its work in the `layoutSubviews` method.

You could subclass `UITabBar` and override said method, but if you go that far, you might want to think about creating your own tab bar, which in the end is just a `UIView` with a few `UIButton`s.

Comment: I see-- thanks for that info. I was figuring that I was going to have to create my own UITabBar (but who really wants to do that!). I am going mess with the layoutSubviews first and see if I can get a quicker solution going that path.

Comment: @RyanG You might want to take a look at the following `UITabBar` alternative: https://github.com/davidmorford/TabBarKit

Comment: Thanks, I have been looking into a few already built custom tab controls (implementing this one right now: https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController) But I am either going to go ahead and use some custom tab control I find or simple resize my images so they aren't as big.. as I would like to keep using native controls as much as possible. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similiar problem with the underlying UITabBarButtons. I solved it by setting the UITabBar's  "Item positioning" attribute to "Fill".

[image]